# Problems with onQueryEvent observable failing upon routing in Nativescript with Angular

Tags: firebase, observable, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

I am using **Nativescript with Angular** and have code written that succesfully calls an `onQueryEvent` from the **nativescript-firebase-plugin** for data set upon first building the application. However after following a route to a second component containing the exact same `onQueryEvent` the data succeeds to retreive a complete list but skips the `onQueryEvent`.

In all honesty I don't know best practices for queries in any situation let alone this one, so I hope it is just a matter of manipulating how I call the `onQueryEvent`.

I believe the problem to be in the firebase.query inside the `getMyTransactionList()` function of the `firebase.service.ts` file.

the `overview.component.html` page has a `transaction | async` `RadListView` that successfully filters upon running `tns run android`.  Then clicking any link directing to the `deal-summary.component.html` page where the function is re-iterated refuses to query by the static `storage` variable set in the `firebase.service`

Here is my code:

**firebase.service.ts**

```
export class FirebaseService {

private _allItems: Array<any> = [];
items: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
public storage: any = '-KomUSGcX-j6qQmY4Wrh'; // set statically to test different routes

constructor(
            private ngZone: NgZone,
            ){}

// fetch data

  getMyDealList(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {
      let path = `deals/${BackendService.token}`;

        let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
             observer.next(results);
          });
        };
        firebase.addValueEventListener(onValueEvent, `/${path}`);
    }).share();              
  }


    getMyTransactionList(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {

      let path = `transactions/${BackendService.token}`;

      // this is a merge of jen loopers giftler code combined with nativescrip-firebase-plugins standard onQueryEvent.  It works on the first load but routing to a second instance of the same function retrieves all the data without queryEvent
    let onQueryEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
             observer.next(results);
          });
        };

      firebase.query(
        onQueryEvent,
        `/transactions/${BackendService.token}`,
        {

            singleEvent: true,

            orderBy: {
                type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                value: 'dealId' // mandatory when type is 'child'
            },

            range: 
              {
                  type: firebase.QueryRangeType.EQUAL_TO,
                  value: `${this.storage}` // this calls a static variable for testing consistency
              }
            ,

        }
    );

        firebase.addValueEventListener(onQueryEvent, `/${path}`);
        console.log("transaction Listener added");
    }).share();              
  }



  handleSnapshot(data: any) {
    //empty array, then refill and filter
    this._allItems = [];
    if (data) {
      for (let id in data) {   
        let result = (<any>Object).assign({id: id}, data[id]);
          this._allItems.push(result);

      }
      this.publishUpdates();
    }
    return this._allItems;
  }


 publishUpdates() {
    // here, we sort must emit a *new* value (immutability!)
    this._allItems.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a.date < b.date) return -1;
        if(a.date > b.date) return 1;
      return 0;
    })
    this.items.next([...this._allItems]);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

**overview.component.ts**

```
 export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    public deals: Observable<any>;
    public transactions: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private router: Router, 
                private firebaseS: FirebaseService,
                ){  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deals = <any>this.firebaseS.getMyDealList();
    this.transactions = <any>this.firebaseS.getMyTransactionList();
  }


  viewDealSumm(id){
         this.router.navigate(['dashboard/deal-summary', id]);
    }
}
```

**overview.component.html**

```
          <RadListView [items]="deals | async ">
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                    <StackLayout (tap)="viewDealSumm(item.id)">
                         <Label [text]="item.dealName"></Label>
                       </StackLayout>
                    </ng-template>
                </ListViewGridLayout>
            </RadListView>





            <RadListView [items]="transactions | async " >
                  <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                       <GridLayout>
                            <Label [text]="item.transName"></Label>
                       </GridLayout>
                   </ng-template>
            </RadListView>
```

**deal-summary.component.ts**

```
export class DealSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

    public transactions: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
                private firebaseS: FirebaseService,
                         ){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.transactions = <any>this.firebaseS.getMyTransactionList();
  }
```

**deal-summary.component.html**

```
     <RadListView [items]="transactions | async " >
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <GridLayout >
                <Label col="1" [text]="item.transName"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </ng-template>
     </RadListView>
```

Comment: This is a very long question and a lot of code for us to review. Is there any way you can shorten the question and just show the code that's relevant to the issue? Refining it would help us to help you! Also, take a minute a read through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)